# Cannot resolve symbol 'play'のコンパイルエラーを解決したい

Tags: java, playframework, intellij-idea

Javaでplayframeworkの勉強をしています。IDEはIntelliJを使っています。
質問なのですが、結論から言うと、**Cannot resolve symbol 'play'のコンパイルエラーを解決したいです。**
現在Controllerクラスのimport play.mvc.*;の「play」でコンパイルエラーが出ています。
インポートしてビルドするとこのようになったので、設定を調べているのですが、解決に至っていないので質問させていただきました。

まず環境は以下です。plyaframeworkとIntellJ初心者のため、バージョンの確認方法から躓いています。。

```
環境 
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
jdk-14.0.1
IntellijJ IDEA 2020.1.2（community無償版）
（prayframeworkのバージョン確認方法が確信が持てず。。）
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.13.2"(built.sbtより)
activator-launch-1.3.5.jar
```

このページを参考にプログラムを作っています。
https://furiblog.com/programming-java-play-setup

以下のようにIntelliJにインポートするとControllerクラスでコンパイルエラーが起きており、playやControllerなどがエラーになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

localhost:9000につなぐと実行できて表示できるのですが、このコンパイルエラーが気持ち悪いです。

もしわかる方がいれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 質問にあるスクリーンショットと思われる画像からは、エラーが起きている事すら判りません。　エラーメッセージを質問に追加して下さい。

Comment: 質問にある通りCannot resolve symbol 'play'のコンパイルエラーになります。またintelijでは赤字のところがエラーになります

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ideaディレクトリを削除し、ビルドし直すとコンパイルエラーが解消されました。プロジェクト固有情報やライブラリ情報が入っているディレクトリになります。

詳しくは左下のBuildタブから前回のビルドを選択し、Reloadをしました。